# Fastest way to return duplicate element in list and also find missing element in list?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, list

So my code is as shown below. Input is a list with exactly one duplicate item and one missing item.The answer is a list of two elements long ,first of which is the duplicate element in the list and second the missing element in the list in the range 1 to n.
Example =[1,4,2,5,1] answer=[1,3]
The code below works.

Am , I wrong about the complexity being O(n) and is there any faster way of achieving this in Python?
Also, is there any way I can do this without using extra space.

Note:The elements may be of the order 10^5 or larger

```
    n = max(A)
    answer = []
    seen = set()
    for i in A:
        if i in seen:
            answer.append(i)
        else:
            seen.add(i)

    for i in xrange(1,n):
        if i not in A:
            answer.append(i)
    print ans
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate for Code Review.

Comment: Optimized code may be completely different to what he posted, so...

Comment: BTW, you're not wrong: your code is O(n). And its problem is, as you noticed, that it also takes around O(n) space complexity

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: (@TigerhawkT3: No, and those guys _are_ touchy.) Assume you can do faster: you would have many elements not inspected. Assume you have two, and try to prove that you might fail to find the answer without these.

Comment: My point was since he's asking for a solution with less space complexity, if it exists, it'd be completely different to his own solution since that one is relying on a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed correct the complexity of this algorithm is O(n), which is the best you can achieve. You can try to optimize it by aborting the search as soon as you finish the duplicate value. But worst case your duplicate is at the back of the list and you still need to traverse it completely.

The use of hashing (your use of a set) is a good solution. There are a lot other approaches, for instance the use of `Counters`. But this won't change the assymptotic complexity of the algorithm.

As @Emisor advices, you can **leverage** the information that you have a list with 1 duplicate and 1 missing value. As you might know if you would have a list with no duplicate and no missing value, summing up all elements of the list would result in `1+2+3+..+n`, which can be rewritten in the mathematical equivalent `(n*n+1)/2`

When you've discovered the duplicate value, you can calculate the missing value, without having to perform:

```
for i in xrange(1,n):
    if i not in A:
        answer.append(i)
```

Since you know the sum if all values would be present: `total = (n*n+1)/2) =  15`, and you know which value is duplicated. By taking the sum of the array `A = [1,4,2,5,1]` which is `13` and removing the duplicated value `1`, results in `12`.

Taking the calculated total and subtracting the calculated `12`from it results in `3`.

This all can be written in a single line:

```
(((len(A)+1)*(len(A)+2))/2)-sum(A)-duplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight optimization (i think)

```
def lalala2(A):
    _max = 0
    _sum = 0
    seen = set()
    duplicate = None
    for i in A:
        _sum += i
        if _max < i:
            _max = i
        if i in seen:
            duplicate = i
        elif duplicate is None:
            seen.add(i)

    missing = -_sum + duplicate + (_max*(_max + 1)/2) # This last term means the sum of every number from 1 to N 
    return [duplicate , missing]
```

Looks a bit uglier, and i'm doing stuff like sum() and max() on my own instead of relying on Python's tools. But with this way, we only check every element once. Also, It'll stop adding stuff to the set once it's found the duplicate since it can calculate the missing element from it, once it knows the max